# How do I output inserted record ID's in order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #TranslationTable(
    OriginalID int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    NewID int
)
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable(
    [TempID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Field1] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE RealTable(
    [RealTableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Field1] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO RealTable
OUTPUT INSERTED.RealTableID INTO #TranslationTable
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM #MyTempTable ORDER BY TempID ASC;
```

I have a bunch of records in my #MyTempTable that as I insert them into my RealTable I want to output the RealTableID into the #TranslationTable in order.  So for example if #TranslationTable and RealTable were empty and I had 3 records in #MyTempTable the #TranslationTable would look like:

```
OriginalID, NewID
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
```

And if say there were already 5 records in the RealTable the #TranslationTable would look like this:

```
OriginalID, NewID
1, 6
2, 7
3, 8
```

My problem is that the INSERT statement doesn't seem to insert and return in the order the the SELECT statement is in, so I get out of order ID's inserted into the #TranslationTable like this:

```
OriginalID, NewID
1, 7
2, 6
3, 8
```

I thought putting the ORDER BY on the SELECT would work, but doesn't seem to be the case.  Does anyone know if this is possible or of a way to make this work?

Comment: There is no "implicit" or "natural" order - don't rely on this! What you could do is output not just the newly inserted `ID`, but also some of the other columns (that you inserted) - enough of them to make it clear and obvious, which row got which new `ID`

Comment: @marc_s Would a loop (row by row insert) fix this?

Comment: @AaronD: well, yes - sort of - since you probably would be inserting a single new row, then it's obvious which row this new `ID` is meant for - but "row-by-agonizing-row" (RBAR) processing in SQL is **very bad** - avoid it if ever possible!

Comment: Should `OriginalID` on `#TranslationTable` be an identity column? Your current `INSERT` statement is putting `Field1` and `Field2` into `RealTable` and throwing `RealTableID` into the `NewID` column of `#TranslationTable`. `OriginalID` isn't (necessarily) going to represent the `TempID` column on `#MyTempTable`

Comment: I wonder if this would work if `OriginalId` were a primary key as well as an identity.

Comment: @marc_s Always well spoken, thank you sir

Comment: Have you tried using a `TRIGGER`?